# YARN container memory not reflected in java Xmx setting

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

Please help me to understand the error in either my understanding or configuration.

I am running Spark on YARN, and have set the minimum container memory allocation to 8GB in yarn-site.xml:

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
    <value>8192</value>
</property>
```

I can see this setting reflected in the Resource Manager UI:

[image]
However, when I ps the container's java process on the server the max heap size is set to 1024MB i.e. -Xmx1024m:

```
root 542 535 1 16:18 ? 00:05:58 /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk/bin/java -server -Xmx1024m -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1583021363029_0011/container_1583021363029_0011_03_000003/tmp ...
```

The container's java process id is **542** :

```
Logs for container_1583021363029_0011_03_000003

0/03/02 16:18:57 INFO executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Started daemon with process name: 542@xxxxxxxx.xxxx.xxx
20/03/02 16:18:57 INFO util.SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for TERM
20/03/02 16:18:57 INFO util.SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for HUP
20/03/02 16:18:57 INFO util.SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for INT
```

Answer (score 1):

Java opts and YARN container sizes are distinct properties

> Maximum heap size settings can be set with `spark.driver.memory` in the cluster mode and through the `--driver-memory` command line option in the client mode

Comment: I am facing a similar issue (posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66986406/spark-yarn-client-mode-1-master-4-slaves-cannot-change-driver-memory-log-fi). Changing the arguments from command line did not work for me.