# Spark YARN client mode (1 master, 4 slaves): Cannot change driver memory. Log file of master shows -Xmx1g

Tags: java, apache-spark, memory, out-of-memory, hadoop-yarn

I am using **spark-2.4.7-without-hadoop** and **hadoop-3.2.2** on an ec2 **cluster** with  **config**:

Master (One ec2 c4.2xlarge) has 16GB RAM and 8vCPUs (4 physical cores & hyperthreading factor 2); 4 slaves (each slave is an ec2 m4.xlarge) each have 15GB RAM and 4vCPUs (4 physical cores).

I submitted an application jar using spark-submit to run on a YARN cluster in client mode. I am triggering the spark-submit on the master machine as follows:

`${SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client --driver-memory 12g --executor-memory 12g --executor-cores 3 --class ClassName App.jar argsToApp`

The spark log file for the master at ${SPARK_HOME}/logs/ had a **-Xmx1g** in the Spark command. This led me to believe that the command line driver-memory was not allocated for my application. Soon enough, my application died with a
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

Sometimes the exception thrown is
`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError : GC overhead limit exceeded`

Another thing I tried prior to the above one: I modified ${SPARK_HOME} /conf/spark-defaults.conf with this

```
spark.yarn.am.memory                12g
spark.yarn.am.cores                 3
```

the log of the master still showed **-Xmx1g** in the Spark command and the application died with a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError : GC overhead limit exceeded`

Related properties from my yarn-site.xml are as follows:

```
  <!-- number of physical cores available per data node -->
  <property>
     <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores</name>
     <value>4</value>
  </property>

  <!-- the total RAM available per data node. amount of physical memory that can be allocated for containers aka amount of memory YARN can use on this node. This property should be lower than total memory of the machine. For example, leave 1GB out of the physical memory for host OS and other daemons-->
  <property>
     <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
     <!-- <value>12288</value> -->
     <!-- <value>16384</value> -->
        <value>15360</value>
  </property>

  <!-- the minimum RAM in MB to allocate per container. These ranges are used for decided whether requested spark executors can be fulfilled or not. If very high number of executors are requested then this min will be allocated to the containers. -->
  <property>
     <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
   <value>8192</value>
  </property>
```

I have already referred to these questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51582475/spark-client-mode-yarn-allocates-a-container-for-driver), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51080595/resource-allocation-with-spark-and-yarn), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63283874/spark-java-cannot-change-driver-memory) (this answer mentions to change the heap size for Java applications - via -Xmx but I am not sure how and where to do that), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60487700/yarn-container-memory-not-reflected-in-java-xmx-setting); and the documentation for spark-2.4.7 [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/running-on-yarn.html) which talks about configuring `spark.yarn.am.memory` and `spark.yarn.am.cores` when running YARN in the client mode.

Please point out what am I missing here. Thanks for your time and attention.

Comment: You're using EC2 rather than EMR? Also you should ideally be running Spark3 with Hadoop3

Comment: Yes, I am using ec2 as a first step before I use EMR for the cluster (I don't fully understand EMR's configuration and cost structure). The app is supported by spark-2.4.7 and some things break when used with spark-3.1.1.

Comment: According to the documentation (question 3 linked) - set java opts in client mode with `--driver-java-options command line option or in your default properties file. spark.driver.defaultJavaOptions`

Comment: Ok, for setting memory in the default properties file, both properties spark.driver.{default, extra}JavaOptions mention that 'Maximum heap size settings can be set with spark.driver.memory in the cluster mode and through the --driver-memory command line option in the client mode."
For the command line option, I tried: --driver-java-options -Xmx12g but I got an error "Could not find or load main class 12g". Can you please point out the right way to do this?

Comment: Use quotes `--driver-java-options='-Xmx12g'`

Comment: Thank you very much. That did not work as spark complained 'Error: Not allowed to specify max heap(Xmx) memory settings through java options (was -Xmx12g). Use the corresponding --driver-memory or spark.driver.memory configuration instead.' I was able to set --driver-memory '12g' but the -Xmx1g in the log file of master persists. Should I try with cluster mode?(if yes, then master machine should also have a worker-executor running on it, right?)

Comment: I would suggest focusing on why you're getting OOM to begin with. The driver should orchestrate jobs to executors, which in general are what do the most work and need more memory. The main reason the driver would OOM is if you're not properly distributing the tasks like using collect() on a large dataframe